# Move button is inactive when trying to export data from ios application to the app's folder in iCloud

Tags: ios, swift

I have developed an iOS app that includes exporting functionality through the use of ".fileExporter." Additionally, I have incorporated support for iCloud Documents and created a container for my application. Upon the app's installation, it successfully generated a folder on iCloud Drive.

However, I have encountered an issue: I can export the app's data to any folder within my iPhone or iCloud, except for the folder created by my app on iCloud Drive. When attempting to export to this specific folder, the "move" button becomes disabled.

I am expecting the export functionality to work with the app's folder.